# Script stops after input?

Tags: python

```
import decimal

print("Choose how you want to calculate tax\n")
print("Type 1 to calculate the tax amount\n")
print("Type 2 to add tax to an amount\n")
print("Type 3 to calculate the amount without tax\n")
choice = input("Type 1, 2 or 3: ")
if choice == int(1):
    amount = input("Enter an amount (with tax included): ")
    tax = input("Enter the tax percentage: ")
    amount = float(amount) / (int(100) + float(tax)) * int(100)
    print("€" , round(amount,2))
```

The script stops after the first input. (Python)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: because `input` returns a `str` and comparing a `str` with `int(1)` (the `int` bit is redundant by the way) is always `False`, you want `if choice == '1':` or  convert the `input` into an `int` and then compare i.e. `choice = int(input....)` and then `if choice == 1:`

Answer (score 0):

`int(1)` (or `int(100)` for that matter) makes little sense as `1` is already an `int`. You can do instead:

```
if int(choice) == 1:
    # ...
```

Or be even more robust:

```
if choice == '1':
    # will not raise an error on non-digit input
```

Answer (score 0):

Small change. Changing choice to `int` prior to comparison

```
...
choice = int(input("Type 1, 2 or 3: "))
if choice == 1:
    ...
```